# Having trouble with running xepersian

Tags: xepersian

I try to use `XeLaTeX` to compile

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{xepersian}
     \begin{document}
      Hello World
     \end{document}
```

And I get the following error:

```
 Runaway argument?
 {\dim_set:Nn ##1{\fontdimen ##2##3}\dim_compare:nNnT ##1={0pt}{\settoheight\ETC.
 ! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \__cs_generate_from_si
 gnature:nnNNNn.
 <inserted text> 
            \par 
 l.1767       \int_case:nnn
                       #2
```

Anything containing `xepersian` seems to generate the same error.

Comment: Have you compiled your code with `XeLaTeX`?

Comment: @Roboticist Yes compiled with XeLaTeX. If I comment out  '\usepackage{xepersian}' it works with XeLaTeX, but including the package creates the error.

Comment: You do not give many clues but I think your `expl3` is too old, update your miktex packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile your code with `XeLaTeX`, you should end up with something like this:

[image]

which is pretty predictable because your left-to-right text is inverted by the right-to-left `xepersian`.

To fix the issue, you can use `\lr{}` to change the direction temporarily. Outside of `\lr{}` everything will be right-to-left again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\lr{Hello World}\\
    سلام دنیا\\
خداحافظ دنیا
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get any output. I just get the error message.

Comment: @Maesumi: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using MIKTEX.

Comment: @Maesumi: Check your directory after compilation. Does `LaTeX` generate any pdf as the output, regardless of the error?

Comment: Yes it does!   And I noticed my package manager does not show an installation date for xepersian.

Comment: Correction. That was an old file generated without xepersian. Upon erasing that file and attempting to compile with xepersian I have no output PDF file.